# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Trying to set IK target to a GameObject but getting this error

Tags: unity

I'm trying to make Player reach for `anchorObject` when Player is within `5f` of it.

However, when I hit Play, the `leftHandEffector.target` is always empty in the Inspector even though I think it should be populated by `anchorObject` based on the code.

How can I get the `leftHandEffector.target` set to `anchorObject` when code runs rather than getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error?

Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using RootMotion.FinalIK;

public class CheckAnchor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject anchorObject;
    public float distance = 5f;
    FullBodyBipedIK ik;

    void Update()
    {
        anchorObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Anchor");

        if (Vector3.Distance(anchorObject.transform.position, this.transform.position) < distance)
        {
            print("Player is close to anchorObject");
        }   
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (anchorObject != null)
        {
            ik.solver.leftHandEffector.target = anchorObject.transform;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Null");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: check to see if anything in `ik.solver.leftHandEffector.target` null. You could try ` ik?.solver?.leftHandEffector?.target` which will return `null` if any members are null, instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed that I wasn't referencing the `ik.solver` code correctly. Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to get Final IK working, here is what I did:

`FullBodyBipedIK ik;` at top of class. And then in Start, `ik = this.GetComponent<FullBodyBipedIK>();`

Then I am able to reference `ik.solver.leftHandEffector.position = targ.transform.position;` as desired and it works.